# How do I get QEMU to open without a BadWindow error after ssh'ing with X11 forwarding?

Tags: ssh, x11, qemu

After ssh'ing to a machine (with -X) I run qemu and get the following:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  25 (X_SendEvent)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x37d
  Serial number of failed request:  14
  Current serial number in output stream:  17
```

But I can run xclock or gedit without a problem.  (So other programs work fine through X11 forwarding.)

How do I get QEMU to run without this error?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here: http://www.pantz.org/software/ssh/badwindowerrorwithqemu.html.

Use the -Y option with ssh instead of -X, to enable trusted X11 forwarding.